# How to update a partial of nested document in mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Here is my document :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5495cfcaec1e18b48015bba3"),
  "Type" : "1", 
  "DomainSize" : "60",
  "Metadata" : { "visit" : "3550", 
                 "website" : "1", 
                 "Specifics" : { "Size:" : "2", 
                                 "Type:" : "Janes",
                                 "Closure Type:" : "Slip-On"}, 
                  "cat" : "2", 
                  "function" : "6"},
  "rate" : " 95.5% "}
```

I want to update few keys from Metadata which I don't know in advance.
My input is a Map of keys and values that exist inside the Metadata list.
I'm wrapping up the given map with another Map that the key is "Metadata" and the value the given map.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> metadata =new HashMap();
metadata.put("Metadata", values);
```

So I'm ending up with a

```
<"Metadata", Map<Key,Value>>
```

Then I used the following:

```
m_collection.update(new BasicDBObject("_id",id) , new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject(metadata)));
```

The record update the existing keys inside the nested map adding `'[]'` to each value and deleting all the keys that are not been update.

For an example the given map is `{'visit': '3558' , 'website' : '20'}`.

After an updated I'm ending up with:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5495cfcaec1e18b48015bba3"),
      "Type" : "1", 
      "DomainSize" : "60",
      "Metadata" : { "visit" : ["3558"], 
                     "website" : ["20"]},
      "rate" : " 95.5% "}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling $set on "metadata" which discards whatever is there and sets the new value with whatever you pass in.  If you only want to partially update a document like that that, you'll either have to pass a complete document to reflect the new state or just issue $set updates: one for each field to change.

Comment: hm... cant i pull the object from the DB and put pull the Metadata value which it a map, then put the update values inside the map fold everything up and put it in the db? I'm just afraid to have to many calls to the DB. in reality the update operation will be called with around 30~ updated values and almost every second (this is just a small part of an application)

Comment: You could do that yes, but it'd be a full round trip for each document.  Maybe that's fine and maybe it's not but you'll need to consider that performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the dotted notation in the field names used for `$set`

See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/